# chkrootkit gives the result tty of process not found

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

i did chkrootkit on my computer and got these results what does it implies

```
Checking `chkutmp'...                                        
The tty of the following user process(es) were not found in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! ger/Install/       0 MA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/defger/Install/ --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-delegated-renderer --enable-impl-side-painting --num-raster-threads=1 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=3676.1.1965219338
! ger/Install/       0 MA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/defger/Install/ --extension-process --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-delegated-renderer --enable-impl-side-painting --num-raster-threads=1 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=3676.2.206
! lt/VoiceTrigger/Install/       0 t/group_16/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50lt/VoiceTrigger/Install/ --extension-process --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-delegated-renderer --enable-impl-side-painting --num-raster-threads=1 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=3676.3.434
! lt/VoiceTrigger/Install/       0 t/group_16/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50lt/VoiceTrigger/Install/ --extension-process --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-delegated-renderer --enable-impl-side-painting --num-raster-threads=1 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=3676.4.146
! root         2298 tty7   /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
chkutmp: nothing deleted
```

i don't know any of these what's happening any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the man page for utmp you will see ...

> The utmp file allows one to discover information about who is
>   currently using the system. There may be more users currently using
>   the system, because not all programs use utmp logging.
>
> Warning: utmp must not be writable, because many system programs
>   (foolishly) depend on its integrity. You risk faked system logfiles
>   and modifications of system files if you leave utmp writable to any
>   user.

So...

- `utmp` should have a list (in binary format) of all running user processes
- `chkrootkit` compares all the user processes running in the system with what is registered in `/var/run/utmp`, reporting the fact that one process being run by root is not registered.

That doesn't mean that it is a rootkit or data logger. *But it might be*.

So you need to track down whether or not this registration is since malware would likely be written to avoid being registered.

Comment: good explanation! do you know what `RUID` is for?

Comment: That is Real User ID and never changes. EUID is the Effective User ID and that one changes per process.